# A sound way to create a default "empty" instance of a Rust struct with type parameters, which wraps a Vec<T>?

Tags: rust

I have a simple struct which is just a wrapper around a `Vec<T>`:

```rust
/// A set-like data structure uses a sorted `Vec` and binary-search.
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct VecSet<T: PartialOrd + Ord + PartialEq + Eq + Hash + Clone> {
    pub(crate) data: Vec<T>,
}
```

I need a way to return a *borrow of* an empty instance of that type - an instance over an empty `Vec` that will never be added to, will never have a mutable reference to it created.  This is a library, and the concrete type of `T` is caller-defined, so there is not a finite set of possible types.

For a variety of reasons, returning `Option<VecSet>` would make a fairly clunky API for callers; allocating a new instance is not an option when returning a borrow.

Allocating a new instance on demand and using, say, `lazy_static` with [`type_map`](https://docs.rs/typemap/latest/typemap/) would work, but would also be, IMHO, overkill - this is literally an object that can never have anything done with it except report its emptiness (and empty results can be returned *a lot*).

Borrowing a pattern that is common in Java, where object size is not a consideration, what I came up with was to statically allocate an instance over a type (`&str` arbitrarily chosen),
convert it to a raw pointer, and then coerce it to the generified type - the thinking being, if it cannot have contents, there should be no code that is dependent on the size of the backing memory buffer because that will always be zero.

```rust
static EMPTY_VEC_SET : VecSet<&str> = VecSet { data : vec![] };

pub(crate) fn empty_vecset<T: 'static + PartialOrd + Ord + PartialEq + Eq + Hash + Clone>() -> &'static VecSet<T> {
    // We need to be able to return a reference to an empty vec set; since it will be
    // immutable, the generic type is irrelevant - allocate once and return a reference as needed
    unsafe {
        let ptr = &EMPTY_VEC_SET as *const VecSet<&str>;
        let ptr2 = ptr as *const VecSet<T>;
        &*ptr2
    }
}
```

Is this actually sound?  Is there some nuance of statics being moved I could be missing?  Is there a vastly simpler way of doing this I'm just not aware of?

Comment: `Vec` is not `#[repr(C)]`, so I don't think the field order is guaranteed to be the same between instantiations. (I think it probably would be, but technically I think it's UB to cast like this.)

Comment: Why do you need borrows of empty instances? This is a surprising requirement, and maybe we should first look into fixing that.

Comment: (I've encountered that requirement myself when implementing `Index` in certain cases, but I'd like to hear what your use case is.)

Comment: Note that an empty `Vec` initializes the data pointer using `NonNull<T>::dangling()`, which returns a pointer that is well-aligned for `T`, so it will be different for different types. I don't think your code is sound.

Comment: What it is is: You're walking a graph of objects, which is a thin wrapper over a graph implemented as arrays of bitsets + a sorted Vec with the objects in question (using binary search to map item to index); and you return subsets to answer queries, where a subset is a bitset + a reference to that Vec.  Empty results are common and some graph algorithms, like closeness centrality, will do `n ^ 3` traversals.  So basically, any place I can shave allocations is a very big win.

Answer (score 3):

This is not sound, as noted in the comments, for variety of reasons:

- You cannot transmute a `Vec`, its layout is not guaranteed.
- The data pointer may not be well aligned for `T`.

However, there is no reason to reach for unsafe code - you can create a generic `const`, it's just a bit clunky. You need to use an associated const:

```rust
fn empty_vec<T>() -> &'static Vec<T> {
    struct Foo<T>(T);
    impl<T: 'static> Foo<T> {
        const VEC: &'static Vec<T> = &Vec::new();
    }
    Foo::<T>::VEC
}
```

When [`inline_const`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2920-inline-const.html) will be stabilized, this will be easier:

```rust
#![feature(inline_const)]

fn empty_vec<T>() -> &'static Vec<T> {
    const { &Vec::new() }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works for `Vec`, but not if what I'm allocating is a `struct VecSet<T> { vec : Vec<T> }` - if I change your example to `const VS: &'static VecSet<T> = &VecSet::new(vec![]);` that fails with *calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants*.  I'll see if there's some way to mitigate that.

Backstory:  `VecSet` is a set-like wrapper around a sorted Vec using binary search;  queries return a `VecSubset` which is `&VecSet` + a bit set with the indices in the vec of present elements.  So `VecSubset` needs a valid `&VecSet` for the empty set.

Comment: I **could** probably turn VecSet into a trait and implement it directly over Vec - but I'm already overloading `Vec<u8/u16/u32/usize/u64/u128>` to be bit-sets, and I'm concerned that the proliferation of methods added to Vec that will wind up in scope for a user of this library could get pretty confusing, at least in what an IDE will offer for code completion.

Comment: Ha! If `VecSet::empty()` is `const fn`, your solution works.

One remaining question: The goal here was not to allocate a new empty Vec and VecSet every time a no-data response is needed.  But won't a creating new `Foo` type on every call with the same `T` still do that?

Comment: Thinking that through further, if it's `const` then Foo<T> must be defined at compile-time for any type passed there.  Got it, I think.